# How to replace column if it is a whitespace when data is inserted

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am inserting data into SQL Server using C#, with code as shown here, but the `name` field can be empty.

```
string name;
string sqlcommand = "Insert into users values ('"+name+"')"
```

I can't change the code right now, but can change database. So I want the `name` column to have a default value.

I have set the default constraint in the database, but it seems like it's not working. Because it's inserted as a whitespace or ''.

I want to know if I enter a empty string like showing above to SQL Server what does it contain, and change it on insert like the code below.

(this is not a working code , it just a example of what kinda code I want)

```
Create Trigger Checking
on Users
after Insert
as 
begin
        if (inserted.Name = '', update Users set Name = 'ello' where Userid = (inserted.userid), "else")

end
```

Thank you

Comment: If you insert an empty string, then the value is `''`, an empty string.  You really should fix the code that does the `insert` so it uses parameters.

Comment: The problem is that I have submit the code to the college . So I cant change the code right now .

Comment: If you don't change your code, then your code will change your database (and maybe even your computer and a whole lot of LAN depending on permissions), just give your code some time. IOW check what SQL injection attack is. That tells you "why you should never code like this and use parameters".

Comment: If you should give this code to college then you have to change, otherwise your code would get a D----- anyways.

Comment: If your `name` parameter originates from any user input you are opening up your database to a *sql injection* attack. There is no need to concatenate values directly, you should always use parameterised queries or a data access framework such as *Dapper* that does it for you easily and by default.

Comment: theres a validation process . this is oversimplified version to better presenting my question . and im just a 1st year, 2nd sem student .  .

Comment: You need to check out some SQL tutorials, because for a start you can't use `IF` in a `SELECT`. And you need to correct use the `inserted` table, I recommend reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I know sql statement is wrong , I was trying to get a work arround , after reading this , https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp . Ill check it out . thank you

Comment: You do realise the link you shared is for MySql, you have tagged your question as Sql Server.

Comment: I did not realised that .Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely cannot revise your code then, to help you out, this is how you could write your trigger to replace `''` with a chosen default value.

Your sample code is syntactically incorrect so I recommend reviewing some tutorials on how to write SQL Triggers. Ideally of course you would pass the correct data from code, and parameterised!

```
create trigger TriggerName on dbo.Users
for insert
as
if @@RowCount=0 return
set nocount on

update u set
   u.[name]='default'
 from inserted i join users u on u.Id=i.Id /* assuming Id is the primary key */
 where i.name=''
```

Comment: Thank you it worked . but I think it throws an sql exception . I am not sure . ill let you know

Comment: @cookie I should have added a caveat it was untested, if you confirm the error I can try to advise if necessary.

Comment: It returnes  2 row updates thats all . and my code expecting only 1 . its not a exception

Comment: Hard to really comment without seeing a working reproducable example - however the trigger will update only row(s) that are inserted and only those with `''` value for the `name` column.
When debugging triggers it's often useful to simulate the inserted data directly using SSMS, you can also alter the trigger to be a `select` to examine the row(s) it would update.

Comment: So i Found a artical that you can hide the "rows affected" im gonna try that now . https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/09/21/sql-server-hide-number-rows-affected-message-set-nocount/ .  if you can comment on how to imply this to your code much appreciated .

Comment: You need `set nocount on` - you can either add `set` options in your client code or [also] in the trigger - I have edited above.

Comment: It doesnt work when Set nocount on . is it something to do with @@rowcount ?

Comment: I should have put it after the `rowcount` check - if you've reproduced that exactly move it to after.

Comment: Okay it works. Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 1):

in case insert (for large transactions) it may affect db performance badly day by day.

default value will be effective for null value only here.

you can use update statement in periodically or after insert activities.